# is it possible to perform ARWorldMap relocalization partially instead of adding all the ARAnchors instantly?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm developing ARKit 2.0 app currently which the user need to find the virtual objects around the mapped space, I had making use the AR Persistence  and i realise after the relocalization of initial ARWorldMap, all object appears instantly even the object which far away from me and had walls between me and the virtual object. Is it possible to only add in the anchor when the current camera detected a plane which is similar to initial World Map session's plane instead of once mapped with initial world map, all anchor has been mapped ?

Answer (score 4):

When you successfully localize to an `ARWorldMap`, your `ARSession` immediately contains all the anchors that were saved in that world map. But that doesn't mean your app has to immediately show whatever virtual content you associate with those anchors.

If you're using `ARSCNView`, your [`renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865794-renderer) callback fires for each of the anchors being restored from the world map, just like it does for anchors you add to the session yourself and for anchors that ARKit adds automatically (plane detection, image detection, etc). And of course, if you're not using `ARSCNView`, there are similar callbacks for other renderers (and in `ARSessionDelegate` if you build your own renderer.)

Your logic in that callback method determines what virtual content gets shown. If you don't want content associated with an anchor to appear, don't add it to the scene in that method. Or add it to the scene but set `isHidden` on it, and use some other logic to un-hide it later.

Comment: @rickster...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842300/in-unityarworldmap-how-will-the-user-know-if-the-gameobjects-are-relocalized

Comment: @rickster Is there a way to partially add something to the scene? So, user creates a 3d model. I want to only save the 3d model and nothing else. Is that possible?