# In UnityARWorldMap, How will the user know if the GameObjects are Relocalized?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I have tested the scene UnityARWorldMap.I have successfully relocalized ARworldmap.Once the models/Gameobjects are relocalized I want the tracking and detected planes to disappear.I found a class called UpdateWorldMappingStatus.cs .I tried to add some code similar to CheckWorldMapStatus method that is I added  function CheckIfRelocalized method.Below is the given code.

```
public class UpdateWorldMappingStatus : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text text;
    public Text tracking;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += CheckWorldMapStatus;

        // I have subscibed to a event
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += CheckIfRelocalized;
    }

    void CheckWorldMapStatus(UnityARCamera cam)
    {
        text.text = cam.worldMappingStatus.ToString ();
        tracking.text = cam.trackingState.ToString () + " " + cam.trackingReason.ToString ();
    }

    void CheckIfRelocalized(UnityARCamera cam)
    {
        if (cam.worldMappingStatus==ARWorldMappingStatus.ARWorldMappingStatusMapped &&cam.trackingState == ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateNormal && cam.trackingReason==ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonNone)
        {
            Debug.Log("Plane Detection Stopped");
            StopPlaneDetection();
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent -= CheckWorldMapStatus;
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent -= CheckIfRelocalized;
    }

    public void StopPlaneDetection()
    {
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface session = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface();
        ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration config = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration();
        config.planeDetection = UnityARPlaneDetection.None;
        config.enableLightEstimation = true;
        //config.enableAutoFocus = true;
        session.RunWithConfig(config);
    }
}
```

In the above code when I click load button the models immediately appear in front of the screen.But If I did not use the CheckIfRelocalized method the models relocalize in their initially set positions while saving but cannot hide the planes.

Comment: I think without restarting the session, I have to hide the planes and tracking?